# Flutter Android Changing hidden status bar colour

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, statusbar

There are existing solutions with tons of questions to hide the status bar with

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    super.initState();
  }
```

But when the status bar is hidden. The hidden area part is black in colour in my app as shown in the picture below, whereas in Whatsapp (see pic) it is able to hide the status bar and using the full screen with the desired colour.

[image: my app with unused status bar space]
[image]

Note: There is no `SafeArea` Widget anywhere in the app.
Please ask if you require any other details

Comment: Most probably you used SafeArea somewhere inside your code. SafeArea will avoid the notch area, bottom bar area etc from rendering your UI. Check for SafeArea in any of your parent widget and remove or modify it.

Comment: Yes, but there is SafeArea anywhere in the app